# Why we won't add +1 to N while calculating quartiles for continuous series?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am been using interpolation formula for calculating quartiles of data in continuous series. My question is Why we write (N+1)/4 & 3(N+1)/4 for Q1 & Q3 while calculating quartiles for individual & discrete series. But N/4 and 3N/4 without +1 for calculating Q1 & Q3 in continuous series. I google for its derivation and essence but couldn't come to the point. So, provide the logic for not using +1 in continuous series quartiles calculation.

Comment: There are about a dozen formulas/methods of calculating quartiles (and other quantiles), some of them purporting to be optimal for specific purposes. R implements nine of them, and in R, '? quantile' retrieves a help page with concise but useful information on these nine (including which other software packages use which). For small N, results can differ markedly depending on the method used. Example: roughly, quartiles are points that divide the sorted sample into 4  'equal 'chunks'. How to do that for. say N = 5 or 11, requires compromises. Methods do not differ consequentially for large N.

Comment: In case you aren't using R, a version of the help page I mentioned is also at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/quantile.html